# PHP - Checking identical values within a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this :

```
[input] => Array (
    [0] => Array ( [val1] => 111 [val2] => 222 [val3] => 333 [day] => 444 )          
    [1] => Array ( [val1] => 111 [val2] => 221 [val3] => 333 [day] => 444 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [val1] => 111 [val2] => 223 [val3] => 333 [day] => 444 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [val1] => 111 [val2] => 224 [val3] => 333 [day] => 444 )
    [4] => Array ( [val1] => 111 [val2] => 222 [val3] => 333 [day] => 444 ) 
           )
```

I only want to check if the first 2 value (val1 and val2) in an array are identical to another array. Like input[0] and input[4] in the example above. How to I do this in php?

I don't want to remove the duplicated array, I just only to return the duplicated value for further use.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the array where you store those keys:

```
$uniq = array();
foreach($input as $v) {
    $key = $v['val1'] . '-' . $v['val2'];
    if (!isset($uniq[$key]))
        $uniq[$key] = 0;
    else
        $uniq[$key]++;
}
print_r(array_filter($uniq));
```

Comment: I don't get it. I am noob in php, correct me if I am wrong. Isn't it the `print_r(array_filter($uniq));`  will print all the va1 and val2 value in another array? Seem like it doesn't check the duplicated value in the input array.

Comment: Okay, finally I got it. I missed the `array_filter` in the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: one more question, what about if I want to print out the `$val1` and `$val2` separately?