# PHP - ensure certain values within multidimensional array are unique

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array.
Here's an example with just two records but there could be many more:

```
array(2) {
[0]=> array(7)
{
[0]=> string(0) ""
[1]=> string(0) ""
[2]=> string(7) "4646468"
[3]=> string(1) "1"
[4]=> string(1) "2"
[5]=> string(10) "2016-08-18"
[6]=> string(0) ""
}
[1]=> array(7)
{
[0]=> string(0) ""
[1]=> string(0) ""
[2]=> string(7) "4646469"
[3]=> string(1) "1"
[4]=> string(1) "2"
[5]=> string(10) "2016-08-18"
[6]=> string(0) ""
}
}
```

I need to make sure that the values for keys 0, 1, and 2 of each inner record are unique. If any of those are not, I want to remove that record (as in, that array element with its 7 values) from the array (however empty strings should be ignored). I found [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545609/5847182) which successfully outputs duplicates for me, but I want to also remove them from the main array. The problem is I do not understand that code at all. I don't understand callbacks and therefore don't know how to modify this code to achieve what I need:

```
$unique = array();
foreach($checked as $v) {
    $key = $v[0] . $v[1] . $v[2];
    if (!isset($unique[$key]))
        $unique[$key] = 0;
    else
        $unique[$key]++;
}
print_r(array_filter($unique));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I settled on in the end:

```
//make sure either serial, asset tag or hostname have been filled in
foreach($laptops as $num => $laptop){
  if (empty($laptop[0]) && empty ($laptop[1]) && empty($laptop[2])){
    $dont_insert[] = $laptop;
  } else {
    $do_insert[$num] = $laptop;
    if($laptop[0]){$hostnames[$num] = $laptop[0];}
    if($laptop[1]){$asset_tags[$num] = $laptop[1];}
    if($laptop[2]){$serials[$num] = $laptop[2];}
  }
}
//check user hasn't entered the asset tag, serial or hostname more than once
if (count(array_unique($hostnames)) < count($hostnames)) {
  //there are duplicate hostnames
  $counts = array_count_values($hostnames);
  $filtered = array_filter($counts, function($value) {
      return $value != 1;
  });
  $result = array_keys(array_intersect($hostnames, array_keys($filtered)));
  foreach($result as $dupe){
    $dupes[$dupe] = $do_insert[$dupe];
  }
}
if (count(array_unique($asset_tags)) < count($asset_tags)) {
  //there are duplicate asset tags
  $counts = array_count_values($asset_tags);
  $filtered = array_filter($counts, function($value) {
      return $value != 1;
  });
  $result = array_keys(array_intersect($asset_tags, array_keys($filtered)));
  foreach($result as $dupe){
    $dupes[$dupe] = $do_insert[$dupe];
  }
}
if (count(array_unique($serials)) < count($serials)) {
  //there are duplicate serials
  $counts = array_count_values($serials);
  $filtered = array_filter($counts, function($value) {
      return $value != 1;
  });
  $result = array_keys(array_intersect($serials, array_keys($filtered)));
  foreach($result as $dupe){
    $dupes[$dupe] = $do_insert[$dupe];
  }
}
//remove any duplicates from our insertion array
if(count($dupes)){
  foreach($dupes as $num => $dupe){
    unset($do_insert[$num]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, modifying the initial code snippet you added:

```
//$main_array contains your original array data.

$unique = array();

foreach($main_array as $key=>$value) {
    $key_combination = $value[0] . '-' . $value[1] . '-'. $value[2];
    //add the key combination to array if it doesn't initially exists
    if (!isset($unique[$key_combination])){
        $unique[$key_combination] = 0;
       }
    //if it gets to this condition means this key combination is a 
    //duplicate and we need to remove the element from main_array
    else{
        unset($main_array[$key]);
       }
}

print_r($main_array);//should contain your original array with duplicates removed
```

## Lets's try this route

```
$unique = array();
foreach($main_array as $key=>$value) {
    $key_combination = $value[0] . '-'.  $value[1] . '-'. $value[2];
    //add the key combination to array if it doesn't initially exists
    if (!in_array($key_combination, $unique)){  //This is the change
        $unique[] = $key_combination;// track duplicates by storing in array
       }
    //if it gets to this condition means this key combination is a 
    //duplicate and we need to remove the element from main_array
    else{
        unset($main_array[$key]);
       }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this - I did start using the original code in this way, and it works except, for some reason, it doesn't work if more than one of the three fields has been filled in. In other words, if _only_ key[0] has data in it that matches another record, it finds it. But if keys 1 and 2 also have data, the code doesn't work.

Comment: Are the values contained in the keys supplied by user inputs and are the inputs sanitized? Try this for the key_combination. $key = trim($v[0]) . trim($v[1]). trim([$v[1])

Comment: Doesn't help I'm afraid. It will find a match across any of the three fields, but only if that one matching field is the only field present of the three.

Comment: Please see my edited post. Try that instead. Lets track the duplicates by storing in an array rather than by making it the key of the array.

Comment: This seems to behave the same way.  Only works if there's only one of the three fields present.

Comment: Can you try this key or value combination: $key =  $v[0]) . '-' . $v[1]. '-'. $v[1]. Lets try put in a glue character in the combination.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through an array and check for unique values in "keys 0, 1, and 2," treating each of these keys *separately* in terms of uniqueness, then I would probably define three arrays *(hashes),* one for each of the three, and then do something like this:

```
$exists0 = array(); $exists1 = array(); $exists2 = array);
...
foreach ($array as $record) {
  if (array_key_exists($exists0, $record[0]) ... you have a duplicate.
  $exists0[$record[0]] = true;  // any value will do ...

  if (array_key_exists($exists1, $record[1]) ... etcetera.
}
```

The *presence* of a key in each of the hashes, `$exists0, $exists1, $exists2`, indicates that the value is a duplicate.  (The value associated with the key ... `true` in this case ... is irrelevant.)

In my example, three hashes are used because I presume that you want to treat the three fields separately. If you want to test for dupes in *any* of the three, the change to my example is trivial and obvious.